# Loading data from a json file to a Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I found one script, but at one place after parsing JSON I'm confused.

The spreadsheet is here :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jE6P-qGzJmIF1AVDjvvywi-IIYVtgxoIHAWW-UeIaFc/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script with my comments where I have stopped:

```
function getContentJSON() {

  let gFiles = "0080076042_jobToCAF.JSON";

  let sheetSpr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let sheetToImp = sheetSpr.getSheetByName("@ACTIONS_REPORT");

  let files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(gFiles);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-16");
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    var headers = Object.keys(json[0]);
    var values = json.map(function(e) {return headers.map(function(f) {return e[f]})});
    values.unshift(headers);

    var  data;

// HERE I decided my own:
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  data = json[i];
  var rows = [];
  for (j in data) rows.push(data[j]);
  sheetToImp.appendRow(rows);
}

// ---------------and above..... 

  }

}
```

Here is an example of the json-file

[image]

The text of my json file is here:

[
{"НОМЕР ЗАКАЗА":"0080076042","СУППОРТ":"00825177","КЛИЕНТ":"AO TANDER","SSCC":"00440000000008251774","АРТИКУЛ":"RU126","НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ":"РОМ, ИЗЮМ, ОРЕХ. Шоколад молочный","Собрано коробов":"18","Всего штук":"216","ЛОГИН":"UFMCKCDRU2","ФИО":"DENIS RUKOVISHNIKOV","МЕСТО СБОРА":"A 701 0049 10","ДАТА ВРЕМЯ СБОРА":"06.09.2021 17:38","Status":"Собран на стоке","ТИП ПОДДОНА":"Пикинг","Место суппорта":"A-708-79-10","DATE TIME READYFORKOPAK":"07.09.2021 14:25:11","TARGET":"TO KOPAKING","PERSON FROM WH":"Рудаковваваавав Дмитрий"}
]

This is a single line json-string.

Comment: What does the JSON data look like? What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: @Kos  if you run the script in spreadsheet, you can see it in variable json after this action "var json = JSON.parse(content);". I can send you another way to see the json file content. Result must download to the current sheet under the titles. order of titles and names are the same like titles in json-file,

Comment: Please provide a sample or screenshot of your json file.

Comment: @Jason E. I uploaded the image of json-file. Is it ok, if there are kirillic words? ))

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov can you make it in a text format so I can create a copy of your json file and test how your code is working now? Else, you can also provide the output you are currently getting with your code now.

Comment: @Jason E. I updated the theme, look above

Comment: @Jason E. can you help me?

Comment: Can anyone help me?((

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov do you encounter any errors?

Comment: the question is not actual now. I decided on my own.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//I decided on my own
var data;

    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      data = json[i];
      var rows = [];
      for (j in data) rows.push(data[j]);
      sheetToImp.appendRow(rows);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).